# how to repeatedly call a function with a list of paired arguments from YAML file to Python using AWS SDK?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3

I want to write a script which takes AWS account's values from YAML file using python boto 3 and create multiple accounts under AWS organization.
Please find the below steps which I want to execute:
**step 1 :** I have list of AWS account's values in YAML file as below:(config.yaml)

```
Name:
   test1
   test2
Email:
    test1@gmail.com
    test2@gmail.com
```

**step 2 :** write a python script to automate the process

```
import yaml

with open("config.yml", 'r') as ymlfile:
    account = yaml.safe_load(ymlfile)

for section in cfg:
    print(section)
    print(account['Name'])
    print(account['Email'])
```

- Pyhon is new for me...I tried with above code to load value from file but it prints only values
- Can anyone help ,how can I load YAML values in below code ?

  - I can create only one account using below simple script:

    ```
    import json
    import boto3
    client = boto3.client('organizations')

    response = client.create_account(
    Email="test1@gmail.com",
    AccountName= "Test1" 
    )
    ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, your config file does not look right. Having two "parallel" lists is rarely a good idea (I suppose this was your intention, even if the dashes are missing). I would give it this structure:

```
accounts:
- name: test1
  email: test1@gmail.com
- name: test2
  email: test2@gmail.com
```

and read it in a way similar to this:

```
import yaml

with open("config.yml", 'r') as ymlfile:
    config = yaml.safe_load(ymlfile)
accounts = config['accounts']
for account in accounts:
    print()
    print(account['name'])
    print(account['email'])
```

---

UPDATE

Maybe you need to do something like this?

```
# ...
for account in accounts:
    response = client.create_account(
        AccountName = account['name'],
        Email       = account['email'])
```

(what an unpythonic naming convention boto3 has!)

Comment: I have tried with above for loop and now I am able to create AWS account and AWS Organization unit when I run both files separate.

Now I got stuck when I merged both YAML and python files as below:

Python file - creates OU and accounts under OU